# Get rid of "comment" field on non-blog pages

Tags: pages, comments, customization

How can I get rid of "comment" field at bottom of page I want to use as a static page or pages on site such as "About" ; "Contact" , etc.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the template file, such as `page.php` and remove the include or call to `<?php comments_template(); ?>`. What theme are you using?